# Need data storage recommendation

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, storage

I am very new to AWS, and I have a use case where I need to store huge amounts of data - approx 60 GB. I also need to look up records in this data by some ID parameter. Which data storage or database service would be recommended for a fast lookup?

Comment: If you can provide more information, we will be more likely to provide an appropriate recommendation. For example: What format is the data (text, CSV, JSON, XML)? Is the data in a single file or many files? Is the lookup just via a single ID? How big is each data record? How "fast" do you require? How will you be accessing the data (eg via an application? Which language?)

Comment: Thanks fir the reply!

Comment: The data is currently with us in a text file where records are separated by newline and fields in a record are separated by comma. But I thought we could migrate it into some database. The data is currently in multiple files. But again this can all be migrated into the same database. The lookup is with a single ID. Each data record is close to 100 bytes. Each record has 5 fields. The data has to be accessed by a Java application on AWS.  Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are several data storage services on AWS:

**Relational Databases**

- **Amazon RDS** (Relational Database Service) provides a fully-managed, traditional SQL database using either MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server.
- You can try using them -- 60GB is perfectly within their scope
- To make them fast, put a Primary Key on the field you wish to use to identify records to retrieve and always retrieve via that field in a WHERE statement
- **Amazon Redshift** is a data warehouse -- it can handle TB and even PB of data and is very quick over large volumes of data. However, it will likely be overkill for your relatively simple requirements.

**Non-Relational Databases**

- **Amazon DynamoDB** is a fully-managed NoSQL database that can be configured to provide an exact number of READS and WRITES per second
- It does not support SQL, but if your goal is to merely store and retrieve data via a unique ID, it will definitely be one of the fastest choices (and you can change the speed as necessary)
- **Amazon S3** can also be considered as a key-value store, where data is kept in files -- the Key is the filename and the Value is the content of the file. Not necessarily as fast as DynamoDB but definitely cheaper since you don't need to "run" a database
- **Amazon ElastiCache** keeps data in RAM, so it would be *very* fast. However, 60GB of storage will require machines with lots of RAM.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot!